# All possible results of a C++ expression?

Tags: c++

According to 5/1 (the Standard):

> An expression can result in a value and can cause side effects.

So obviously we have two possible options:
1) Expression results in a value and cause side effects
2) Expression results in a value and doesn't cause side effects

What are the other possible options?  (For example are there any expressions which don't result in a value?)
I thought about throw-expressions and functions with `void` return type. Can we refer them to the first or second category (value of `void` type with possible side effects)?

Comment: A void expression does not result in a value.

Comment: Should be migrated to English Language (just kidding (kinda))

Comment: It's probably wise to treat exceptions differently from other side effects. In particular, when a sub-expression throws, the full expression isn't evaluated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are the other possible options?

3. Expression doesn't result in a value and causes side effects
4. Expression doesn't result in a value and does not cause side effects

Expressions with `void` return type do not result in a value. Expressions in 4. do not affect the behaviour of the program.

Comment: 4 might be useful in debugging, depending on your tools. But other than that, spot on.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I changed wording to accommodate.

Comment: Do you mean that expressions in 3 and 4 return void?

Comment: 6. Expression crashes the program (no return, no side effects within the process). Example: `*(char*)nullptr = 42` However, from a C++ language perspective, one should probably rephrase this: 6. Expression exposes undefined behavior.

Comment: @M.M Thanks. I suspected that was the case. I removed since I think the distinction is off topic.

Comment: @cmaster C++ answers usually have an implied "unless the program causes undefined behaviour in which case anything can happen"

Comment: According to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9565169/7123797) 5. can be subset of 4 too. "Exceptions are a slightly awkward special case, in that altering the flow of control does change the state of the abstract machine (by changing the current point of execution), but isn't a side-effect. The code to construct, handle and destroy the exception may have its own side-effects, of course."

Comment: @Rodvi side-effects of function calls involved in a side-effect are not considered side-effects of the original expression  (they have different sequencing too)

Comment: @M.M Nevertheless, undefined behavior like a crash is definitely different enough from all the "normal" results that it's worth mentioning. I mean, we even have standardized functions that *intentionally crash the process* like `abort()`. You can neither say that `abort()` has no side effects (it crashes the process), nor that it has side effects (the process won't notice a side effect, it'll just be dead).

Answer (score 0):

Given that `exit(0)` is an expression, we must include the possibility that evaluating an expression ends the program.