# Static storage objects optimization on thread context

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, storage-duration

Can a compiler optimize a static storage object in multithread program context? I'm asking it to know if a variable declared as static, for instance, generates a side effect when used in a function called in a thread.

```
bool flag = false; // static storage duration object

void f(){ //function called in a thread
  flag = false;
  // do some work...
  flag = true;
}

//a possible representation of the code above after optimization
void f(){
  flag = true;
  // do some work...
} // is this possible to happen?
```

I read some answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563600/what-exactly-is-a-side-effect-in-c), but I didn't find anything that could help.

Comment: Even if the standard would garantee that assinging and reading from a static storage duration object would be considered side effect, it would have to effect on the thread safety. Thread safety is a completely different beast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static storage duration has no affect on thread safety.  In your example the second code block would be legal as long as the reordering doesn't break anything inside `f`.

You still need synchronization on all shared objects that any thread writes to.  In this case you could get that by using a `std::atomic<bool>` for `flag` like

```
std::atomic<bool> flag = false;
```

---

The rule for thread safety is that if you have an object shared between multiple threads, and at least one of them is a writer, then you need synchronization.  If you do not then you have a data race which is undefined behavior.