# Void fucntions not passing parameters c++

Tags: c++

So I have a void function that is going to randomly generte a structure:

This is the structure:

```
struct przeciwnik{
  string nazwa;
  int HP;
  int DMGmax;  
};
```

And the function:

```
void przeciwniklos(przeciwnik przeciwnik1)
{
  przeciwnik1.HP=rand()%51 + 100;
  przeciwnik1.DMGmax=rand()%1 + 25;
cout << "HP przeciwnika: " << przeciwnik1.HP <<endl;
}
```

And in the main function:

```
przeciwnik przeciwnik1;
 Ekwipunek eq1;

 srand(time(NULL));

  przeciwniklos(przeciwnik1);
```

However the HP and DMGmax stays 0.
I tried using int przeciwniklos() but I couldn't return a structure,

Comment: You need to read up on references. Right now you're modifying a local copy and then throwing that out.

Comment: Since you're using C++ you really should be working towards implementing this as functions *on the `struct` itself*. There's no reason to use this kind of procedural style when C++ gives you all the tools to write functions to initialize and/or modify an object as you wish. What you have here arguably should be in the constructor, minus the `cout` debugging code.

Comment: You are copying the structure in the function. To modify it in the function, you have to pass it as a reference. Change the function call to `void przeciwniklos(przeciwnik& przeciwnik1)`. The `&` indicates that it should be treated as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this code you are passing variable to function by value then function make copy of your function and do all works then since it's passed by value it has side [effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563600/what-exactly-is-a-side-effect-in-c#:%7E:text=A%20side%20effect%20is%20a,function%20has%20finished%20being%20evaluated.) you should return then assign to struct or make by reference.

return value:

```
przeciwnik przeciwniklos(przeciwnik przeciwnik1)
{
  przeciwnik1.HP=rand()%51 + 100;
  przeciwnik1.DMGmax=rand()%1 + 25;
  return przeciwnik1;
}
your_data_strucutre = przeciwniklos(your_data_strucutre);
```

pass by refrence:

```
void przeciwniklos(przeciwnik& przeciwnik1)
{
  przeciwnik1.HP=rand()%51 + 100;
  przeciwnik1.DMGmax=rand()%1 + 25;
  cout << "HP przeciwnika: " << przeciwnik1.HP <<endl;
}
przeciwniklos(your_data_strucutre);
```

pass pointer:

```
void przeciwniklos(przeciwnik* przeciwnik1)
{
  przeciwnik1->HP=rand()%51 + 100;
  przeciwnik1->DMGmax=rand()%1 + 25;
  cout << "HP przeciwnika: " << przeciwnik1->HP <<endl;
}
przeciwniklos(&your_data_strucutre);
```