# Post-increment operator behaviour w.r.t comma operator?

Tags: c++, post-increment, comma-operator

In the following code:

```
int main() {
   int i, j;

   j = 10;
   i = (j++, j+100, 999+j);

   cout << i;

   return 0;
}
```

The output is **1010**.

However shouldn't it be 1009, as `++` should be done after the whole expression is used?

Comment: Related: see [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/) and [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), and read up on "Sequence Points" which were introduced in C++11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comma operator is a sequence point: as it says in the C++17 standard for example,

> Every value computation and side effect associated with the left expression is sequenced
>   before every value computation and side effect associated with the right expression.

Thus, the effect of the `++` operator is guaranteed to occur before `999+j` is evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

> `++` should be done after the whole expression is used?

No. The postfix operator evaluates to the value of the old `j` and has the side effect of incrementing `j`.

Comma operator evaluates the second operand **after** the first operand is evaluated and its side-effects are evaluated.

> A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right;
>   the left expression is a discarded- value expression (Clause 5)<sup>83</sup>.
>   Every value computation and side effect associated with the left
>   expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect
>   associated with the right expression.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7784819/2805305

Answer (score 3):

Associativity of the comma operator is left to right.

So starting from `j++`, this will be evaluated first (`j` becomes `11`)

Then `j + 100` is evaluated (no use)

Then `999 + j` is evaluated which is equal to `1010`

This rightmost value is assigned to `i`

Thus, the output is `1010`

**Long Answer:**

### Built-in comma operator

> The [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) expressions have the form
>
> ```
> E1 , E2
> ```
>
> In a comma expression E1, E2, the expression E1 is evaluated, its
>   result is discarded (although if it has class type, it won't be
>   destroyed until the end of the containing full expression), and its
>   side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression E2
>   begins (note that a user-defined operator, cannot guarantee
>   sequencing) (until C++17).

This already answers your question, but I'll walk through it with reference to your code:

Start with something simple like

`int value = (1 + 2, 2 + 3, 4 + 5); // value is assigned 9`

Because *...the expression E1 is evaluated, its result is discarded...* Here, since we have more than 2 operands, the associativity of the comma operator also comes into play.

> However shouldn't it be 1009, as '++" should be done after the whole
>   expression is used?

Now see:

```
int j = 0;
int i = (j++, 9 + j);
```

Here, the value of `i` is 10 because *...and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression E2 begins...* Hence, the incrementation of `j` has its effect before the evaluation of `9 + j`.

I think now you can clearly understand why your

```
j = 10;
i = (j++, j+100, 999+j);
```

**`i` is assigned a value of 1010**.

Comment: I'm on my mobile, so I couldn't write a quality answer with good formatting :P

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks for editing it! I'll improve this at morning, it's midnight rn lol